# Why is msbuild duplicating entries in web.config transformations?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, web-config-transform

I am using web.config transformations to insert entries into the web.config for certain build configurations.

E.g. my Web.Test.config has this entry:

```
<elmah>
    <errorMail from="me@me.com" to="me@me.com" async="false" smtpPort="25" smtpServer="mail" subject="test.senegal.co.uk Exception" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</elmah>
```

This works absolutely fine building from visual studio.

However when creating a deployment package using msbuild, the  entry is duplicated in the web.config. This obviously causes an exception.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

My "master" config is Web.Master.config *not* Web.config. The web.config file gets overwritten on build in visual studio. I think it must have something to do with this.

What I think is happening is msbuild is transforming web.config rather than using the Web.Master.config.

The question is how to tell it to use the right master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added `/p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=false` to the msbuild parameters, as my web.config was already being transformed in a BeforeBuild target like so:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
   <TransformXml Source="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Web.Master.config" Transform="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Web.config" />
</Target>
```

Comment: You made my day.

Comment: If you're looking for a solution to this from inside visual studio (2019), go to properties\PublishProfiles\{your file}.pubxml and add a property to the propertygroup: <TransformWebConfigEnabled>False</TransformWebConfigEnabled>

Answer (score 3):

In my case duplication was caused by `xdt:Transform="Insert"`. If remove it from Web..config and leave the rest it will work properly, e.g.:

```
<!-- doesn't work -->
<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="My" 
     xdt:Transform="Insert" />
```

vs.

```
<!-- works -->
<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="My" 
     />
```

Comment: Did not work for me VS2019... removing the insert directive made it not insert the group at all.

Comment: @BrienMalone: sorry, this is a 7 years old answer. I don't remember already. I'd encourage you to ask a new question.

Comment: @abbatischev I didn't catch that -- fair point!